# C++ - Assigning port to UDP client using two machines

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, client, port

I'm setting up a basic UDP server/client application using winsock on two separate machines on the same LAN using a switch. I need to send data down a specific port from the client to the server.

How I've done it so far is server is two sockets (one for sending, one for receiving) and binded the receive port to 7777. Client also has to sockets (one for sending, one for receving) sends a message to port 7777.

Now on the `recvfrom()` function, I get the senders port to be some arbitrary number 35708. However I want the senders port to be say 8000.

My question is, can I specify which port the message is sent from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use bind() before sendto(), you can choose to set the port, or let the network stack determine the port.

```
struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
...
myaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); /* where PORT is defined elsewhere */
```

or

```
myaddr.sin_port = htons(0); /* if zero, let the system determine the port */
```

BTW, I don't know if this matches your use case, but you don't need to setup two sockets for bi-directional communication. See, for example: http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/sockets/udp.html

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure that out aswell. I have seen that link before and have used it for bidirectional communication. My main issue was trying to force the client to send on a specific port number which `bind()` seems to have worked. Another question in itself is that if I only use one socket for send/receive, the sender receives it own message which was rather strange hence why I've used two sockets